# How do I use rails assets without sprockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, assets, sprockets

I have created a new rails app with the --skip-sprockets flag. I added a single root route to a simple hello world welcome#index as in the tutorial and I have updated the associated stylesheet. When I request the page, I get the error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css")`.

I had hoped to avoid sprockets, as this is a simple website and I just wanted to drop the newest boostrap in public without headache. I assume without sprockets now my public folder isn't automatically populated at all. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your assets files (javascript, css, images) in the public folder, example: `/public/application.css`

Then in your application layout file replace `stylesheet_link_tag 'application'` by `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/application.css">`

You will have to do the same for javascript. Also you will not be able to use `image_tag` or `asset_path` helpers

Explanation: everything which is in `public` folder will be rendered by your web server without going through the rails application